# Singleton in Java

Tags: java, singleton

Is this singleton implementation OK in a multi threaded application given: there is no serialization, deserialization

```
public class NewSingleton {

    private static final NewSingleton RAJNI= new NewSingleton();

    private NewSingleton(){

    }

    public static NewSingleton getInstance() {
        return RAJNI;
    }    
}
```

Comment: There are at least a score of same question in SO , Browse through them.

Comment: Problem of this implementation is that instance will be created on class loading (first import of the class).

Answer (score 6):

This is fine if you make the class `final` but I prefer

```
public enum NewSingleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

as it is much simpler IMHO.